# What natural astronomical object is rare on a Hubble volume scale?

Tags: universe, observable-universe

There are some milestone objects on different scales of the universe.

- The star is a notable feature on a solar system scale
- The supermassive black hole is a feature on a scale of a galaxy
- ??

The tricky part is that I am looking for something localizable. Great attractors, galactic filaments, and [other easily findable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cosmic_structures) are features alright, but they are, unsurprisingly, very big and hardly bounded.

Are there any rare objects that appear only on a [Hubble volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_volume) scale (a proper volume of $\sim (c/H_0)^3$), but have definable boundaries?

EDIT: The lifetime of these objects should be at least millions of years.

EDIT': Red spirals fit the kind of objects I am looking for, but unfortunately, they are not rare enough. As @ProfRob pointed out they are only two orders of magnitude less frequent than usual galaxies.

I think that as long as an object is more frequent than a quasar it is too common.

Comment: How rare? How long lasting?  For example quasars are several orders of magnitude more rare than galaxies, yet there are still about a million of them known.  They also are (on a galactic scale) short-lived, the black hole will be active for a while (and form a quasar) then quiet.  So the Andromedeans may not be seeing the same quasars that we see, since they are a couple of million light years from us.  Many rare objects are rare because they are short lived (and so only visible in a "light shell") Do these "count"?

Comment: A nice example might by voørwerps.  I think only seven are known,  but again they are probably short-lived and only visible from particular perspectives.

Comment: The two examples given (stars and SMBHs) represent the centers of highly inhomogeneous systems. The universe that we see is homogeneous, so we have no reason to think there's a center. There may be objects with number density of order $H^3$, but they won't be "milestones" in the same way.

Comment: @JamesK, quasars are a good fallback option, I thought that if nothing else would come up, large quasar groups are the objects I am looking for. They are localized and are relatively rare compared to galaxies. They live long enough for my purposes: millions of years are ok.

Comment: Ultraluminous quasars are almost there at around 10 per Hubble volume in the present-day universe. Whether they "live" (as quasars) very long is another matter - presumably not, which is partly why they are rare.

Comment: @ProfRob, how does one distinguish between ultraluminous quasars and the usual ones? Is there a gap between them, or is it just the top N quasars by luminosity?

Comment: No gap, just a diminishing number of more and more luminous objects. The most luminous example was published just this month,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space density of ultraluminous quasars (those with luminosities greater than $5\times 10^{13}L_\odot$) in the local universe is $\sim 10^{-9}$ (Mpc)$^{-3}$ (see for example [Caplar et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.3719) and the plot below).

[image: Space density of quasars vs redshift]

The local Hubble volume of $(c/H_0)^3$ is $\sim 8 \times 10^{10}$ (Mpc)^3, so there would only be $\sim 100$ ultraluminous quasars in the local Hubble volume.

However, there is a population of *even* more luminous quasars in the distant universe, at least to $\sim 10^{16}L_\odot$ (see the plot below from [Shen et al. 2020](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/495/3/3252/5841290)). There is ONE rare example at $z<1$, which is what you are looking for. The quasar SMSS J114447.77-430859.3 at $z=0.83$ (just about in the local Hubble volume) has a luminosity of $\sim 2\times 10^{14}L_\odot$ and is claimed to be "*the most luminous QSO in the last 9 Gyr*" [Kammoun et al. 2023](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/522/4/5217/7100972)). This fits the bill if it is long-lived enough.

[image: Quasar luminosity functions at various redshifts]

Comment: Sounds very nice. Do you have a nice plot with the qusar luminocity distribution? I followed the linkes, but as I understand plots in these papers are much more specific

Comment: @FrogOfJuly Pictures added. You can see what the estimated space density is at $z \sim 0$ and then in the second plot you can see that there are even higher luminosity quasars seen at high redshifts - where their comoving space density is higher - but there is AFAIK only one known quasar with $L > 5\times 10^{47}$ erg/s with $z<0.9$.